# Bootstrap, css, progress bar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I do not understand why my progress bar does not work. I guess something is wrong with my css options for bootstrap. I have tried to change the options to find out where the problem is, but I did not have a success.

view

```
 <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped">
 <div class="bar" style="width:20%"></div>
 </div>
```

css

```
.progress {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f9f9f9);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f9f9f9);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#f5f5f5), to(#f9f9f9));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f9f9f9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f9f9f9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f9f9f9);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f5f5f5', endColorstr='#f9f9f9', GradientType=0);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.progress .bar {
  width: 0%;
  height: 18px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background-color: #0e90d2;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #149bdf, #0480be);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #149bdf, #0480be);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#149bdf), to(#0480be));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #149bdf, #0480be);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #149bdf, #0480be);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #149bdf, #0480be);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#149bdf', endColorstr='#0480be', GradientType=0);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.6s ease;
  -moz-transition: width 0.6s ease;
  -ms-transition: width 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition: width 0.6s ease;
  transition: width 0.6s ease;
}
.progress-striped .bar {
  background-color: #62c462;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 100% 0, color-stop(0.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.25, transparent), color-stop(0.5, transparent), color-stop(0.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, transparent), to(transparent));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  -webkit-background-size: 40px 40px;
  -moz-background-size: 40px 40px;
  -o-background-size: 40px 40px;
  background-size: 40px 40px;
}
.progress.active .bar {
  -webkit-animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
  animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
}
.progress-success .bar {
  background-color: #5eb95e;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #62c462, #57a957);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #62c462, #57a957);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#62c462), to(#57a957));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #62c462, #57a957);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #62c462, #57a957);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #62c462, #57a957);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#62c462', endColorstr='#57a957', GradientType=0);
}
.progress-success.progress-striped .bar {
  background-color: #62c462;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 100% 0, color-stop(0.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.25, transparent), color-stop(0.5, transparent), color-stop(0.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, transparent), to(transparent));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good - however, to make the progress bar "work" you must also specify an update to the inline style for `width`.

There are many ways to do this, but you must select the one that best serves the experience of your page or pages.  For example, you might have 5 pages, like you would in a survey. The progress bar would be persistent element on each page.  As you create each page, you will want to change the inline style for width, perhaps something like this:

```
<div class="bar" style="width:20%"></div>
<div class="bar" style="width:40%"></div>
<div class="bar" style="width:60%"></div>
<div class="bar" style="width:80%"></div>
<div class="bar" style="width:100%"></div>
```

As you do so, the visualization of your progress bar will be updated. There are many ways to do this in both single pages and multiple pages, but the above is just one example.

Here as a working example for you to play with:

http://jsfiddle.net/dusthaines/jjdTt/

Comment: m... I am using this example for Ruby on Rails Upload https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example/blob/master/app/views/uploads/index.html.erb and they do not use multiple lines with width, I need the same, but my specific bootstrap options

Comment: And I thought that those bootstrap options somehow deactivate the feature they have in example